# Displaying HTML in WP7

Tags: html, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

So I was looking for a way to display HTML in WP7 (binding it to datacontext) and a generous dude here suggested that I use the MPS Toolkit, that provides HTMLViewer and HTMLTextBox components to WP7. so I did and at the beginning it looked great. the html was displayed exactly how I wanted but for some pages it throws the following exception:
The property 'Margin' was not found in type 'Paragraph'
I've been sitting 2 days trying to fix this problem without luck!
I though it was because of some attributes in the xaml but I was wrong, it's something in the html that this library doesn't like.
Does anyone know about a solution for this? or maybe another suggestion for displaying html in wp7 (not webbrowser).
Anything would be REALLY appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with using WebBrowser? All you need is an attached property that will be able to invoke the HTML rendering method ([NavigateToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)) with the content you pass to it.

Comment: Becouse you can't do transparent background for webbrowser, for example.